# Xcode subproject is not building

Tags: c++, xcode

ALL,

I have a weird situation.

I have an Xcode project which compiles and run fine.

However one of the subprojects is not building at all. It is a dylib subproject and I'm not yet trying it out.

Could someone please help me solve this?

Is there a limit on the number of subprojects I can create in Xcode?

Below are the screenshots of what I'm talking about:

[image: Project tree]

[image: Build tree]

As you can see the libtablewindow project is not being built.

Could someone please help?

TIA!

EDIT:

This is the "Product" menu from the Xcode. The project "libtablewindow" is listed:

[image]

And this is an "Edit Schema" window. What do I check here?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It can be more than one problem you have there, but as good starting point, You need to check if target supposed to build your dylib as product, has been added as target to the project scheme in order to been built by project build.
You can check that by going to Product -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme.
Also, maybe it is added to the scheme but not for current build configuration(Debug or release for example), you can check all that at same place in Xcode.

**Now** we can see, that, explicitly stated for build in your project is just one target, any other were built implicitly, using dependency resolving. Please click on button with + (plus) sign. Dialog for choosing targets to add will be shown, from which you can choose your dylib target to add to the project build. After you finish that, just close the dialog, and build project as usual. The same way you can add or remove other targets from project, and manage build configurations.
I hope this helps.